# Process on Duplicate Record Item

Tags: trigger, process-builder, visual-workflow, process

We use Duplicate Record Items and Duplicate Record Sets in order to merge Account records. I want when merge occurs to have a process to update the status (Custom field) of Duplicate Record Set. I would prefer to use a process or a flow rather than a trigger. Is it possible somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to my problem by creating a new Process Builder functionality. Since merge operation cannot be triggered (delete and update events occur), i created a process on Duplicate Record Set Object and checking the number of Duplicate Record Items. If it gets reduced, then update the field of DRS.